# AudioKit example MicrophoneAnalysis's maximum frequency

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, audiokit

I'm writing an application which analysis the sound of frequency about 16kHz to 18kHz on iPhone. The example code of MicrophoneAnalysis can only analysis the frequency below 12kHz, so I'm wondering what limit the upper bound of the MicrophoneAnalysis, the sample rate set or the frequency analysis algorithm and how to improve the upper bound?

I have read the document of the iPhone and find that the maximum sample is 44.1kHz and the analysis the recording file using iPhone and find that the bandwidth of the microphone is enough for sound lower than 20kHz, so the hardware may not be the problem

Thanks in advance for anyone can give help

Comment: I've not used the AudioKit, but my guess would be the Analysis algo. I've built a spectrum analyzer and certainly have had access to the full frequency range. My advice would be to capture the audio directly and do your own processing, it's really not that difficult.

Answer (score 2):

Sound frequency and sample rate are not the same thing.
If your sample rate is 44.1khz, your frequency is 20khz.

See [here](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/25053/sampling-frequency-vs-audio-frequency?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), and [here](http://productionadvice.co.uk/high-sample-rates-make-your-music-sound-worse/) for more.

Comment: Thank you for answering. According to the Nyquist sampling, if the sampling rate is 44.1kHz, the upper bound of the audio bandwidth should be 20kHz, but the APP can only analysis the frequency lower than 12kHz and I don't know what limit the APP

Answer (score 0):

Most contemporary iOS devices can run the audio input ADC at a rate of 48000 samples per second.  Thus, analyzing frequencies up to a bit below (thus not including) 24 kHz should be possible using your own DSP analysis algorithms.  Perhaps the library you are using has other constraints, such as wide transition bands in the anti-aliasing filter(s), or an internally decimated sample rate.